# vue-router - where to place autlogin when using router.beforeEach

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

We have a router global navigation guard which redirects to login page if the user is not logged in:

```
router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
  if (to.meta.requiresAuth) {
    if (!store.getters.isAuthenticated) {
       next('/login');
       } else {
           next()
       }
   } else {
      next()
   }
}
```

We only want to run store.dispatch('autologin') once when the Vue App is loaded. We can't put it before router.beforeEach as the autologin uses our axios configuration which uses a store again.

When we put in our main component `App.vue` the autologin is called after the router navigation guard.

It works if we do it like this in our main.js

```
store.dispatch("autologin").then(() => {
        new Vue({
            store,
            router,
            render: h => h(App)
        }).$mount("#app");
    }
);
```

But this looks rather strange. What is the best place to initialize the authentication before mounting the app?

Comment: Not sure what exactly `autologin` action does but how about `created` lifecycle hook in `App.vue` ? That hook is called before `mount`.

Comment: "created" as any other component lifecylce hook is called after router.beforeEach(). Autologin logs the user in (Remember-me)

Comment: You're right. I'm assuming `App.vue` as the main wrapper component. As all other components will be the children of this component, it'll have the same effect. Before mounting `App.vue` means kind of like before mounting the app. But if you really need to do something before that, I think what you have looks good to me.